# Inner join between three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have 3 tables called

- Companies
- Contacts
- Campaigns

Contacts has foreign key  of companies. Companies has foreign key of campaigns. All of them have a column 'name'. I need a join table which will have contact name company name and campaign name.

```
contact
id   name company_id
companies
id   name campaign_id
campaigns
id   name company_id
```

Comment: can u post what have u tried so far and show ur table structure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select con.name as contact_name , com.name as company_name,campa.name as campaign_name
from contact con inner join company com
on con.companyid = com.companyid
inner join campaign campa
on com.campaignid = campa.campaignid
```

assuming id columns of respected tables

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT contacts.name,companies.name,campaigns.name 
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN 
(companies INNER JOIN campaigns 
ON campaigns.campaignid=companies.campaignid) 
ON contacts.companyid=companies.companyid
AND //add any additional filters HERE
```

hope this was helpful