# Eloquent in Laravel-Datatables, select in select?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I have 3 tables, the 1st has a FK from the 2nd, and the 2nd has a FK from the 3rd:

```
Table 1: [admin_demandas]
-------------------------
id_demanda|   projec_id
-------------------------

Table 2: [admin_projec]
-------------------------
id_projec |   sub_id
-------------------------

Table 3: [admin_sub]
-------------------------
id_sub    |   name
-------------------------
```

What I need is to get the 'name' from Table 3 but starting with the Model of the table 1.

I was trying something like this:

```
$data = AdminDemanda::select([
    'id_demanda',
    'admin_projec.sub_id AS sub_id',
    'admin_sub.name AS name',])
    ->join('admin_projec', 'admin_demandas.projec_id', '=', 'admin_projec.id_projec')
    ->join('admin_sub', 'admin_projec.sub_id', '=', 'admin_sub.id_sub')
    ->get();

return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
```

I've done my Datatables with only 1 JOIN (2 tables) but not sure how to do those 2 JOIN (3 tables). I got this error:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'admin_projec.sub_id' in 'on clause'
```

What should I modify in my query?
Should I need to use query builder instead Eloquent, with a DB::raw() query?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this:

[Inner join between three tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293122/inner-join-between-three-tables-in-mysql)

it was simple... now in case anyone need it, my Datatable query is:

```
$datos = AdminDemanda::select([
    'id_demanda',
    'admin_dis.nombre AS nombre_dist',
    'admin_sub.nombre AS nombre_subes',
    'mes AS mes_demanda',
    'admin_sistemas.nombre AS nombre_sistema',
    'admin_demandas.demanda_mwh AS mwh'])
    ->join('admin_projec', 'admin_demandas.proyeccion_demanda_id', '=', 'admin_projec.id_proyeccion_demanda')
    ->join('admin_sub', 'admin_projec.subestacion_id', '=', 'admin_sub.id_subestacion')
    ->join('admin_dis', 'admin_projec.dist_id', '=', 'admin_dis.id_dist')
    ->join('admin_sistemas', 'admin_projec.sistema_id', '=', 'admin_sistemas.id_sistema')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Glad you've figured it out. For best practise try to resolve this issue later in time with Eloquent. It will work out a lot better than using a lot of joins as suggested by @Raccoon. It will eventually make all this relationships between tables a lot more easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a lot but I couldn't get it. But I know, I must take advantage of what Laravel offers

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your models

By exemple in `AdminSub` model

```
public function projec(){
    return $this->hasMany(AdminProjec::class , 'sub_id');
}
```

You should be able to do

```
\AdminSub::first()->projec();
```

And continue by editing your `AdminProjec` model with the same kind of relationship

```
public function demandas(){
    return $this->hasMany(AdminDemandas::class , 'projec_id');
}
```

And now you could try

```
//I do not remember which one will works
\AdminSub::first()->projec()->first()->demandas()->name
//or 
\AdminSub::first()->projec()->first()->demandas()->get()->name
```

Comment: The code I put was an example, the 2nd table has like 4 FK that points to another tables, is there another way to make the query instead editing the models? will works anyway this Model thing? thanks, I will try it later.

Comment: Using model is the best way to work with database relationships, I think. Because you set them up only once and everything will work at any time. If you change a table name of field name, you just have to edit a few things to make it run. If you use full query with join, you will have to edit each page where you use this table/field and it can be a real nightmare once your application become bigger